# Building an offline installer Debian CD

Tags: debian, system-installation

I have to build an installation CD to help other people set up a Debian server with Apache/Mysql/PHP and our application.
The CD must install the full system offline (because the servers will be installed in Africa, without any internet access). It is for a Non-Governmental Organisation.

Using simple-cdd, I already have a CD which installs everything, but it still needs internet access for several packages. How can I correct this? The installer gets package files from the Debian mirror.

Comment: From what I understood [in `simple-cdd`s HowTo](http://wiki.debian.org/Simple-CDD/Howto), it should do *exactly* what you describe, i.e. pre-fetch all packages so the installer CD doesn't depend on an internet connection.  Have you got any details, what you tried, what could have failed with using `simple-cdd`?

Comment: It should, but it does not. On the ISO created by simplecdd I only have packages requested in profile.packages file, and none of dependancies of my packages. I handled this by reading from installation logs wich packages are installed, and added them to the packages list file.

Comment: Maybe a little bit off-topic, but Fedora can build a Live Media(CD/DVD) with packages I wanted. I just [built my own Fedora Live Media](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_and_use_a_Live_CD) with GNOME+LXDE Desktop/Eclipse/LibreOffice/Flash-plugin/audio video codec from 3rd party repositories/rgba font antialiasing. This live media can also used for offline installation. If Debian is an option, maybe you can try Fedora.

Answer (score 1):

Which packages are those, exactly?

In general, if you can't remove them from your collection, you'll have to rebuild the packages so that their install scripts do not try to access the net any more.

Comment: xorg and dependancies, gcc, etc... it is not the install scripts wich access the net, but the installer process itself.